# Is this a good example of using abstract classes?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have to hold a short presentation about abstraction at work tomorrow. I tried something out of my understanding but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. But it works fine.

Basically I have three `TextBox` and one Button controls on my `Form`. I can enter something in the first two `TextBox` controls, press the `Button` control and the added up result is shown in the third `TextBox`. If it is a number, the sum is shown. If it is something else, it will handle it as a string and just concatenate it.

Main-Method:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbstractAddUp numberadding = new Numbers();
        AbstractAddUp stringadding = new TextStrings();

        //not really important, they are just used to satisfy parameters of int.Parse() method
        int firstnumber;
        int secondnumber;

        //If values in textboxes are numbers...
        if (int.TryParse(tbFirstOperand.Text, out firstnumber) && int.TryParse(tbSecondOperand.Text, out secondnumber))
        {
            object a = (object)(tbFirstOperand.Text);
            object b = (object)(tbSecondOperand.Text);
            tbResult.Text = numberadding.addValues(a, b).ToString();          
        }
        //...otherwise, if they are of some other type, treat them as string
        else
        {
            object a = (object)(tbFirstOperand.Text);
            object b = (object)(tbSecondOperand.Text);
            tbResult.Text = stringadding.addValues(a, b).ToString();
        } 
    }
```

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractAddUp
{
    //abstract method that does the actual calculation or concatenation
    protected abstract object DoOperation(object a, object b);

    //public method to be called to initiate calculation/concatenation
    public object addValues(object a, object b)
    {
        return DoOperation(a, b);
    }
}

public class Numbers : AbstractAddUp
{
    //overridden method for adding two numbers
    protected override object DoOperation(object a, object b)
    {
        int firstnumber = int.Parse(a.ToString());
        int secondnumber = int.Parse(b.ToString());

        int result = firstnumber + secondnumber;

        return (object)(result);
    }
}

public class TextStrings : AbstractAddUp
{
    //overridden method for concatenating two strings
    protected override object DoOperation(object a, object b)
    {
        string strA = a.ToString();
        string strB = b.ToString();

        string result = strA + " " + strB;

        return (object)(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear because abstraction as a general term has nothing to do with abstract classes.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a good example, because I don't understand it from reading it. But just a comment. Other people might be able to explain better :-)

Comment: Your abstract class has virtual methods, virtual methods != abstract methods.

Comment: What you're doing looks like it would be better suited for an Interface.

Comment: You would be better having a base class with the abstract method `Add` then have derived classes implementing them. One could use string and concat, other could use ints. that would be a better example. You could use a generic T in the base class and swap that out in derived classes with required type (string and int). The abstract class could derive from IAdd which would mean consuming classes would rely just on IAdd and wouldnt care if adding strings or ints

Comment: If your abstract class does not have abstract method then abstract class=interface.

Comment: ok I have changed some code

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think that's a good use of an `abstract class`. No useful implementation is shared between the classes, and no methods are truly shared. Your example is so simple that you should use simpler code.

```
//Check if value in textbox is a number or something else and add up
if (int.TryParse(tbFirstOperand.Text, out firstnumber) && int.TryParse(tbSecondOperand.Text, out secondnumber))
{              
    tbResult.Text = (firstnumber + secondnumber).ToString();
}
else
{
    tbResult.Text = tbFirstOperand.Text + " " + tbSecondOperand.Text;
    // or
    tbResult.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", tbFirstOperand.Text, tbSecondOperand.Text);
}
```

If you might want to add up similar types in different ways, e.g. maybe strings are added with a space in the middle and maybe with a comma in the middle, then it might be useful to have something more complicated. If it were such a situation that would benefit from some sort of polymorphism, I think a good way would be a generic `interface` or `abstract class` (as a rule of thumb, if the `abstract class` provides no implementations or `protected` properties you'll use, you could probably use an `interface` instead):

```
interface IAddUp<T>
{
    T Add(T left, T right);
}
```

Or if you make the interface take `object`s and have the implementation take care of how that's handled (but with a higher risk of a runtime failure)

```
interface IAddUp
{
    object Add(object left, object right);
}
class AddIntegers : IAddUp
{
    public object Add(object left, object right)
    {
        return (int)left + (int)right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a very good example of an abstract class, as the class doesn't have to be abstract at all for the code to work. The point of having an abstract class is that it doesn't work of its own, it needs something from a concrete implementation to make it complete.

Here is an example of an abstract class, where the class combines strings in different ways, and the concrete implementations tell how to combine them:

```
public abstract class Combinator {

  // the base class needs to ask for the separator to use
  protected abstract string GetSeparator();

  public string Combine(string value1, string value2) {
    return value1 + GetSeparator() + value2;
  }

}

public class SpaceCombinator : Combinator {

  // the subclass needs to implement the abstract method for the code to compile
  protected override string GetSeparator() {
    return " ";
  }

}

public class DashCombinator : Combinator {

  public override string GetSeparator() {
    return "-";
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
Combinator combinator;

combinator = new SpaceCombinator();
string name = combinator.Combine("John", "Doe");

combinator = new DashCombinator();
string phone = combinator.Combine("555", "524 855");
```

Comment: ok I have tried changing my code based on your example. can you please make a quick review and check if it better now?

Comment: @LeonidasFett: Yes, that look better, but you should just use `string` for the parameter types instead of `object` as you are really passing strings around everywhere. Just a note; if you edit your original question, then other people won't understand the answers to it. You should rather add the updated code instead of changing the original.

Comment: thanks for the help, I understand it now a little better thanks to your example. unfortunately I don't have my other code anymore, but I will keep that mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking on same lines are Tim but wouldn't be using an `if`. Dependent types would expect the `Add` class and wouldnt care if it was `AddStrings` or `AddInts`. Alternatively, the base class could inherit from an interface to go one step futher.

You could then have a factory class deciding which type to return, your application from then on does not need to know, nor would it care.

```
public abstract class Add<T>
{
    public abstract T AddSomething(T left, T right);
}

public class AddStrings : Add<string>
{
    public override string AddSomething(string left, string right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}

public class AddInts : Add<int>
{
    public override int AddSomething(int left, int right)
    {
        return (left + right);
    }
}
```